# csh script as executable does not setenv

Tags: environment-variables, csh, tcsh

I am not able to set `env` variables through an executable `csh/tcsh` script

An `env` variable set inside a `csh/tcsh` executable script "myscript"

contents of the script ...

```
setenv MYVAR /abc/xyz
```

which is not able to set on the shell and reports "Undefined variable"

I have made the `csh/tcsh` script as executable by the following shell command

```
chmod +x /home/xx/bin/myscript
```

also the path is updated to

```
set path = (/home/xx/bin $path)    
which myscript    
/home/xx/bin/myscript
```

When I run the script on command line and echo the env variable ..

```
myscript
echo $MYVAR
MYVAR "Undefined variable"
```

but if i source on command line

```
source /home/xx/bin/myscript
echo $MYVAR
/abc/xyz
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to `source` your code rather than execute it so that it is evaluated by the current shell where you want to modify the environment.

You can of course embed

```
 source /home/xx/bin/myscript
```

within your `.cshrc`

the script does not need to be executable or have any `#!` shebang (though they don't hurt)

Comment: Thanks guys  @Carpetsmoker , appreciate your comments , will do the source , but my confusion of how was it working earlier is still not yet clear in my mind , i am on RHEL 5.5

Answer (score 1):

This is not how environment variables work.

An environment variable is set for a process (in this case, `tcsh`) which is passed on to all child processes. So when you do:

```
$ setenv LS_COLORS=foo
$ ls
```

You first set `LS_COLORS` for the `tcsh` process, `tcsh` then starts the child process `ls` which inheres `tcsh`'s environment (including `LS_COLORS`), which it can then use.

However, what you're doing is setting the environment is a *child process*, and then want to propagate this back to the parent process (somehow). This is not possible. This has nothing to do with `tcsh`, it works like this for any process on the system.

It works with `source` because `source` reads a file, and executes it line-by-line *in the current process*. So it doesn't start a new `tcsh` process.

I will leave it as an exercise to you what the implications would mean if it *would* be possible :-) Do you really want to deal with unwise shell scripts that set some random environment variables? And what about environment variables set by a `php` process, do we want those to go back in the parent `httpd` process? :-)

---

You didn't really describe what *goal* you're trying to achieve, but in general, you want to do something like:

```
#!/bin/csh -f                                                               

# ... Do stuff ...                                                          

echo "Please copy this line to your environment:"
echo "setenv MYVAR $myvar"
```

Comment: Thanks , my setup is legacy, it was supposed to run through ~/.cshrc where  ~/.cshrc is always sourced on command line and contains "myscript" in one of the lines .. i do not know why is it running on some linux machines and why is it showing the behavior you had just explained... i am confused