# Update Environment outside process in python

Tags: python, shell, csh

I have created simple script which is available inside shell but not outside shell. is it possible to get enviroment outside shell

```
#!/bin/csh -f
# Added to avoid load of .cshrc.${USER}
module unload m(package name) 
module load m/default
which Milky
```

Comment: related: (similar issue but for `bash`) [Calling the “source” command from subprocess.Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7040592/4279)

Comment: I am able to execute script. So package available inside process and not available outside process

Comment: [You can't update the parent's process environment directly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/496702/4279). Read [my answer and see how `env -0` and `os.environ` can be used together to update parent's environment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22086176/4279)

Comment: I have gone through thread but could not understand env-0 concept. How is work  @J.F. Sebastian

Comment: [`env -0`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) is a command that prints the current environment ending each output line with NUL (zero byte) instead of the newline (to allow literal newlines in the values).

Comment: But in this case, it's accessing env variable. But I am trying to load this want to available in another section of Program as command line. if I am load and call function which will be access Milky as a command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csh script as executable does not setenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738107/csh-script-as-executable-does-not-setenv)

Comment: But it's does not contain solution